# If one wants to use matrices in such way that one does "per dimension" transformations, then is the matrix suitable?

Tags: matrices

If one wants to use matrices in such way that one does "per dimension" transformations (e.g. if the dimensions are $x_1, ..., x_n$, then one would like to do $f_1(x_1), ..., f_n(x_n)$), then is the matrix suitable?

That is, because when one uses matrices for e.g. multiplication, the element $a_{ij}$ in the result $AB$ is the dot product between row $i$ in $A$ by row $j$ in $B$.

But doesn't this mean that one applies "other dimensional" modifications to the original elements? That is, $a_{11}$ may be in "first dimension" (whatever one uses it for), but in the matrix multiplication all the effects of the other $n-1$ dimensions are also summed to this, because one sums over the entire row and column, rather than just performs the operation on that single element. So the resulting $a_{11}$ reflects not only "modifications" done in the first dimension, but all the $n-1$ other as well.

So if using matrix transformations for "per dimension processing", how is the matrix used?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking. Could you maybe try to be clearer, perhaps by providing an example ?

Comment: The way you're using the word dimension doesn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: I think you mean to say you want to change each component of the vector without involving the other components? In this case you would have a diagonal matrix, where all nondiagonal entries are $0$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Yeah, perhaps that's the way.

Comment: @krirkrirk: I think that if, in the OP's question, you replace "dimension" with "coordinate" every time it appears, it'll make a lot more sense. Not perfect, but close.

Comment: In matrices the dimensions do refer to what coordinates they apply on. The dimensions appear as the number of rows and the number of columns. Depending on the application it might make more sense to use either term or something else as well.